# Modify X-axis measures in Saiku

Tags: graph, mdx, saiku

I have created one line chart using saiku. When I integrate it to a dashboard , its x-axis fields are getting overlapped. how can I eliminate this issue?

My MDX query is given below.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Price] as '([Prices].[Price].CurrentMember.FirstSibling)'
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Price]}  ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY  CrossJoin({[Product Names].[Product Name].[${NAME}]},CrossJoin({[Price Dates].[Date].Members},{[source].[source].Members}))  ON ROWS
FROM [MY Cube]
```

Here in the x-axis the fields showing Product name,Date, and source. I just need date in X-axis but when i point to the point in the line of the graph , there all the three parameters should show.